# Date Picker not Visible in React Native Date Time Picker Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker, react-native-datetimepicker

I am using react native date time picker modal to pick dates in my react native application. It was working fine but suddenly the date picker is not visible any more, only the confirm and cancel buttons are visible and the dates themselves are not visible any more. The code is shared below :

```
 <View style = {{width : "25%", backgroundColor : "#037f8b", alignItems : "center", justifyContent : "center", zIndex : "200"}}>
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{setDateVis(true)}}>
                                    <Image style = {{resizeMode : "contain", width:"45%", height:"45%"}} source = {require("../assets/calendar.png")}/>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                <DateTimePickerModal
                                isVisible={dateVis}
                                mode="date"
                                isDarkModeEnabled={Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark' ? true : false}
                                onConfirm={handle_date}
                                onCancel={()=>{setDateVis(false)}}
                                />

            
                            </View>
```

[image]